# Add a background image to pdf export of an org-beamer file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

I'd like to add a background image to a single page in a pdf I am creating with `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf` using the Metropolis theme (no relation). The use of the theme doesn't appear to be the root of the issue, but I'm mentioning it for completeness.

I have tried

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\mode<beamer>{\usetheme[numbering=none, progressbar=frametitle, titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis}}
* Heading
** Page title
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{nifty-image.jpg}}
  - First list item
  - Second list item
```

and variation on this approach, including placing `\usebackgroudimage` on the Heading or Page title lines, prepending it with `#+LATEX_HEADERS:` and wrapping it in curly braces. The best result I can get is having the image displayed on the page, but it either covers the text instead of showing up behind the text, or it appears above or below the text.

Is there a way to either add transparency to the image and simply do an `\includegraphics` or to  change how I use `\usebackgroundtemplate` to display the image, well, in the background?